# How many complexes modulo a prime $p$ are of multiplicative order $p^2 - 1$?

Tags: ring-theory, complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic, intuition

If $i = \sqrt{(-1)} \bmod p$, $p$ prime,  does not exist, then we can form numbers of the form $a+b i \bmod p$ with multiplicative order $p^2 - 1$.  How often do these numbers occur modulo $p$?  In other words, how many complex values of the form $a+b i \bmod p$, where $a$ and $b$ are taken from $\mathbb{Z} /p \mathbb{Z}$ have multiplicative order $p^2-1$?

**PROBLEM RESTATEMENT**

As Joanpemo points out, I'm looking for the number of elements of multiplicative order $p^2 - 1$ in the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ with $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, and $p$ prime.

Comment: I find the wording a little confusing. Your first words mean "If $\;-1\;$ is not a quadratic residue modulo some prime $\;p\;$ , then we..."?

Comment: And *where* are we looking for multiplicative order equal to $\;p^2-1\;$ ? In what ring, field,...?

Comment: @Joanpemo:  Both components $a$ and $b$ are modulo $p$.  I look for a prime $p$ where the imaginary essentially does not exist.  For example, $2^2 \equiv -1 \bmod 5$, so the imaginary unit essentially exists in this ring.  I look for rings where the imaginary does not exist.  This is I believe a two-valued ring.  In other words, we have the complexes modulo a prime $p$.  I'm not sure exactly how to describe it.  It may be $\mathbb{C} /p \mathbb{C}$.  It's the complexes, where both components are taken modulo a prime $p$.

Comment: The reason I'm looking for complex "rings", as I guess they'd be called, are because I can get a ring of large size, where the components (real and imaginary) are small.

Comment: Well, we can say the following: $\;-1\;$ is a quadratic residue modulo some prime $\;p\;$ iff $\;p=1\pmod 4\;$ , so you're looking forward to work with some prime $\;p=3\pmod 4\;$ , like $\;p=7,11,23\;$ , etc. Now, in the prime field $\;\Bbb F_p\cong\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ , the polynomial $\;x^2+1\in\Bbb F_p[x]\;$ is irreducible, so you can talk of the field extension $\;\Bbb F_p[\sqrt{-1}]\;$ of degree two of $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ , which itself is the field $\;\Bbb F_{p^2}\;$ with $\;p^2\;$ elements. I'm not sure though if you can handle this algebraic mumbling so far...

Comment: @Joanpemo:  I believe I understand it - it looks like you have the field correct!  I'm really trying to determine roughly how many elements, then, in this field have the greatest multiplicative order, $p^2 - 1$.  I'm looking for the asymptotic bounds to this number...  Really it's for an algorithm to find one element of greatest multiplicative order.  My idea is that if I know the asymptotic bounds, I can use it for a randomized algorithm to determine how long it will take to find one element of greatest multiplicative order.  So really, I'm just trying to find one element of greatest order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking of the field $\;\Bbb F_{p^2}\;$ , then the multiplicative group of this, $\;\left(\Bbb F_{p^2}\right)^*:=\Bbb F_{p^2}\setminus\{0\}\;$ is a cyclic group (as is **any** finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of **any** field), and in this case it is a group of order $\;p^2-1\;$ , so you're looking for the number of generators this group has, and this number is exactly $\;\phi(p^2-1)\;,\;\;\phi=$ Euler's Totient Function..

Thus, you can search in the net for asymptotics of Euler's Function, or perhaps only take this function as it is.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you for taking the time to understand my question and explain a little abstract algebra to me, as my algebra's more than a bit shaky.  This question is in regards to an algorithm, like I said, so you have helped me with it, too.